# How do I redistribute Windows Imaging Component with .NET Framework 2.0?

Tags: .net, winforms, photo, wic

I have a .NET Framework 2.0 app and would like to use the Windows Imaging Component. Since my application is a WinForms app and will be redistributed to users via an MSI installer I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this.

I see a couple of options:
1) Skip .NET 2.0 and build on .NET 3.0 which includes the Windows Imaging Component
2) Figure out a way to include the WIC component with my installer

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WIC is built into Windows Vista so you don't need to distribute it for Vista machines.  For XP it is available as download from Microsoft [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=8E011506-6307-445B-B950-215DEF45DDD8&displaylang=en).

Comment: +1, and it appears every Windows version starting with [XP SP3 as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Component), and .NET starting with 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with WIC but can you just set the Copy Local property on the reference to true?  I would assume that the needed assembly would then be available to you when you create your MSI.

My solution would probably just be to build on the newer framework.  I believe MSI can be setup to install it if necessary.